# Check if email is in json object

Tags: php, json, api

Consuming a Restful API I get a json object structured as follow:

```
[
    {
        "id": "123456",
        "name": "example",
        "email": "example@gmail.com",
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": "789123",
        "name": "example2",
        "email": "example2@gmail.com",
        ...
    }
]
```

I need to check if an email is in the json object and get id and name. Can I perform this search using PHP?
Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on the returned results like this:

```php
<?php
$jsonObject = '[
    {
        "id": "123456",
        "name": "example",
        "email": "example@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "789123",
        "name": "example2",
        "email": "example2@gmail.com"
    }
]';

$collection = json_decode($jsonObject);

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    if ($item->email === 'example@gmail.com') {
        // Matching item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

User array_search function

```
array_search('example2@gmail.com', array_column($array, 'email'));
```